# scanning NSMutableArray for part of a string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Im new to iphone programming and im kinda stuck with my current project. I got a text file with a lot of data in it. Data is sorted like this:

```
51398030 10003254 80211593/94     1301281744 TOMTOM100  
51398030 10003254 80211593/94     1301281744 TOMTOM101  
51398030 10003254 80211593/94     1301281745 TOMTOM102  
51398030 10003254 80211593/94     1301281745 TOMTOM103  
51398033 10003254 80211595        1301281744 TOMTOM100  
51398033 10003254 80211595        1301281744 TOMTOM101  
51398033 10003254 80211595        1301281745 TOMTOM102  
51398033 10003254 80211595        1301281745 TOMTOM103  
51398029 10003254 80211597/98     1301281744 TOMTOM100  
51398029 10003254 80211597/98     1301281744 TOMTOM101  
51398029 10003254 80211597/98     1301281745 TOMTOM102  
51398029 10003254 80211597/98     1301281745 TOMTOM103
```

I already imported this txt file and created a NSMutableArray that contains each line as object. Now i have a textfield where the user can enter a number. the app should now look trough the text file and and sort out the lines containing this number.

I already looked at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC

but i dont know how to start.

This is how far i got:

```
    NSData *tmpData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL       URLWithString:trackTraceFileUrlName] ];
    NSLog(@"%@",trackTraceFileUrlName);
    //convert data to string 
    NSString *tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tmpData              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *piecesArray = [tmpString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    NSMutableArray *trackTraceContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:piecesArray];
    NSLog(@"*%@*",trackTraceContent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably want to search over all the lines in the array, and assuming that you array just contains the strings as NSString objects:

```
NSArray *stringArray; // assuming that you already have these variables
NSString *numberEnteredByUser;
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(id obj, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSString *str = (NSString *)obj;
    return [str rangeOfString:numberEnteredByUser].location != NSNotFound;
}];
NSArray *results = [stringArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Of course, you can also create the target array without using NSPredicate, by just iterating over `stringArray` and adding the right objects to a NSMutableArray `results`.

Comment: Could you give an example for my out going situation? I edited my question.

Comment: NSPredicate may also be created like: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", enteredValue], where enteredValue - value entered by user in textField. I guess it more clear in this situation.

Comment: Ok looks great and simple. I get one error:

'NSPredicate *findStringWithReference = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",cRText.text];
    NSArray *trackTraceContentFiltered = [piecesArray filterUsingPredicate:findStringWithReference];
No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'filterUsingPredicate:' What im doing wrong?

Comment: Its just a typo. Use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` instead of `filterUsingPredicate`.

Comment: Cool thanks its working now! can someone post this as answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
NSString *str = <string on which you want to search>;

    NSRange r;
    if ((r = [str rangeOfString:@"the string you want to search"]).location != NSNotFound)
        //string found..
```

I think you have an array so try the modified one

```
for (NSString *str in <array>)
{
    NSRange r;
    if ((r = [str rangeOfString:@"the string you want to search"]).location != NSNotFound)
        //string found..
}
```

Comment: This is working but how would i put all the lines that are containing this code in a new array?

Comment: @user1805901 create a new NSMutableArray and add r [array addObject:r]; where sanjit shaw say's //string found. Actually I'm an idiot I'm guessing sanjit shaw just added for loop to answer your comment,.

Comment: @BooRanger that does not work:
Sending 'NSRange' (aka 'struct _NSRange') to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Comment: @user1805901 ya sorry youl'll have to use range on the string, so NSString *newString = [str substringWithRange:r];

Comment: This is not exacly what im looking for. Now i just get as output 4 times the number the user entered because its found 4 times in the txt. I want to get as output the line that contains the text the user entered.

Comment: Within the if block print the object "str" in log an check is it working or not. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the number entered by the user is the primary search into your data, **and it's unique**, then hold your data in a dictionary, not an array, using the *number* as the key:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
MyObject obj = ...;
[dictionary setObject:obj forKey:obj.number];
// etc.
```

Look-up will be **much** faster, as this is precisely what dictionaries (hash tables) are for.

Note: Objective-C collection classes can only hold objects, so you will need to represent the *number* using an `NSNumber` object, not a primitive type.

If the *number* is not **unique** then you can still use this technique, but you'll need to hold a dictionary of arrays, using the *number* as the key into that array, which complicates things somewhat.  However you will still gain performance benefit doing this.

Comment: The problem here is that the number will change every week. The text document stored data that will be updated every week.

Comment: @user1805901 That doesn't matter; the collection is in memory and the text file will have to be parsed each time the app starts anyway.  My approach is really only worth the effort if the text file is very large, else you may find it easier to stick to your existing implementation (using arrays).

Comment: Ah ok. This would be not what im looking for we are currently trying to keep the file as small as possible to keep the data transferred as small as possible.